# Deleting 3d Dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I made a function to initialize a dynamic 3d array

```
void initialize_array_3d(char ***Array, int size1, int size2, int size3)
{
    Array = new char**[size1];
    for (int t=0; t<size1+1; t++)
    {
        Array[t] = new char *[size2];
        for (int r=0; r<size2+1; r++)
        {
            Array[t][r] = new char [size3];
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine but when I try to delete it with a function

```
void deinitialize_array_3d(char ***Array, int size1, int size2)
{
    for (int t=0; t<size1+1; t++)
    {
        for (int r=0; r<size2+1; r++)
        {
            delete[] Array[t][r];
        }
        delete[] Array[t];
    }
    delete[] Array;
}
```

My program crashes, why? and how do i fix it?

In main:

```
int main()
{
    char ***Failed;
    initialize_array_3d(Failed, 5, 4, 2);
    deinitialize_array_3d(Failed, 5, 4);
    Failed = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To fix this, just use std::vector, so you don't have to worry about deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters function `initialize_array_3d` is wrong. It should look at least the following way

```
void initialize_array_3d( char ****Array, int size1, int size2, int size3 )
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    *Array = new char**[size1];

    for ( int t = 0; t < size1; t++ )
                     ^^^^^^^^^
    {
        ( *Array )[t] = new char *[size2];

        for ( int r = 0; r < size2; r++ )
                         ^^^^^^^^^
        {
            ( *Array )[t][r] = new char [size3];
        }
    }
}
```

That is the first parameter should be passed indirectly using pointer.

A function call might look like

```
initialize_array_3d( &Failed, 5, 4, 2);
                     ^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise parameter `char ***Array` is a local variable of the function and the function deals with a copy of the argument. Any changes of the local variable do not influence on the original argument.

Or you could declare the parameter as reference to the pojnter. For example

```
void initialize_array_3d( char *** &Array, int size1, int size2, int size3 )
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    Array = new char**[size1];

    for ( int t = 0; t < size1; t++ )
                     ^^^^^^^^^
    {
        Array[t] = new char *[size2];

        for ( int r = 0; r < size2; r++ )
                         ^^^^^^^^^
        {
            Array[t][r] = new char [size3];
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the function call might look like

```
initialize_array_3d( Failed, 5, 4, 2);
                     ^^^^^^
```

As for function `deinitialize_array_3d` then it should look like

```
void deinitialize_array_3d(char ***Array, int size1, int size2)
{
    for ( int t = 0; t < size1; t++ )
                     ^^^^^^^^^ 
    {
        for ( int r = 0; r < size2; r++ )
                         ^^^^^^^^^
        {
            delete[] Array[t][r];
        }
        delete[] Array[t];
    }

    delete[] Array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `size1 + 1` to loop through your array instead of `size1`, but because the array is of `size1`, you can't access element `size1`. In the initialization you're getting away with it (it's undefined behavior), but you can't delete memory you don't own, so your program crashes.

---

Consider using a `std::vector` instead.